# Not able to receive email as Input claim via query string when calling to rest api service deployed on azure

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I am facing an issue while calling a custom rest api deployed on azure app service.
I have a created a technical profile which calls a custom api and that api accepts an email of use who is trying to login. but some how email is empty.I tried with `email`,`signInName` and `signInName.EmailAddress` but everything is empty. below is my technical profile.

```
  <!-- technical profile to get the reset value -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AppFactor-GetMfaResetValueWebHook">
          <DisplayName>Reset mfa web hook</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://XXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/v1.0/Auth/oauth/getresetmfa</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">QueryString</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isResetMfa" PartnerClaimType="isResetMfa" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

the above technical profile is getting the value of MFA status by email and passing it for further actions. below is my `SignupSignIn` user journey.

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn" DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftAccountExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MicrosoftAccountExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MSA-MicrosoftAccount-OpenIdConnect" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Demo: The following orchestration step is always executed. 
         This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they 
         include the AppCode MFA attributes 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">

          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AppFactorGetMfaResetValueWebHook" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AppFactor-GetMfaResetValueWebHook" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>

        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_isResetMfa</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_isResetMfa</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="ConditionalAccess_Evaluation"/>
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Demo: The following orchestration step is executed only for unregistered 
        accounts (new created account or if user cancel the sign-up process). 
        It generates a verification app secret key for the user (none interactive step). -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>extension_StrongAuthenticationAppSecretKey</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AppFactorGenerateTotpWebHook" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AppFactor-GenerateTotpWebHook" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Demo: The following orchestration step is executed only for unregistered 
        accounts (new created account or if user cancel the sign-up process). 
        It registers a verification app through QR code that mobile authentication app should scan. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>strongAuthenticationAppQRCodeBitmap</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AppFactorRegisterExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AppFactor-Register" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Demo: The following orchestration step is executed only for registered accounts.
        It asks the user to provide the TOTP code and verifies the provided code (using validation technical profile). -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="11" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>strongAuthenticationAppQRCodeBitmap</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AppFactorChallengeExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AppFactor-Challenge" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Demo: The following orchestration step is always executed.
        It updates the verification app time step matched for a given user in the Azure Active Directory.
        An error is raised if the user does not exist. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="12" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADWriteUserAppCodeByObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-WriteUserAppCodeByObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="13" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

below is my Relaying party :

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />

    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <!-- Demo: Allow JavaScript execution in the relying party policy-->
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />

      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isResetMfa" PartnerClaimType="isResetMfa" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.I have tried few links but nothing helped.

Please help me to resolve.
Please let me know if you need anything else.
Thanks

Comment: You need to look at all technical profiles called via your orchestration steps prior to the call to `AppFactor-GetMfaResetValueWebHook`, and determine which field/claim the user enters the email into, or where it may be read from the directory. The claim must be an output claim as part of the technical profile that is called from the user journey. You can use this tooling to see the content of the claimbag to help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#troubleshooting-with-application-insights.

Comment: Most likely what you want is `signInNames.EmailAddress` -> you may have missed the "s".